# What kind of conversion is this code doing?

Tags: c, unions

I ran across this code, where they are trying to convert from float to int

```
int val[5];
union {
    int i;
    float f;
} conv;

... 
val is updated with some value
...
case OUT_FORMAT_FLOAT:
for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
   conv.f = val[i];
   val[i] = conv.i;
}
```

But I am just not able to understand how this would work. The `val[i]` is assigned to `conv.f` and then the `conv.i` is used store back the value into `val[i]`. `conv` is a union type since we are using `f`, `i` will not have a valid value right?

Am I missing something here?

Comment: refer http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/other_data_types/#unions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's doing something called [*type punning*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_punning).

The thing to remember here is that floating point values are often stored in a very different format than integers (most commonly [IEEE floating point format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point)), and the use of the union is to get the raw floating point format.

To be more specific, this is what happens:

1. The assignment `conv.f = val[i]`. This converts the integer in `val[i]` to a floating point value, and stores it in `conv.f`.
2. The assignment `val[i] = conv.i`. This gets the raw floating-point bit-pattern stored in the union, and assigns it to `val[i]`.

This works because a union is not like a structure with separate members. In a union all members *share* the same memory. Modifying one member of the union will modify all members.

---

A note on why a union is used: This conversion could be made in other ways as well, but then that would break [the strict aliasing rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule), however using unions for type punning is allowed.

Comment: I think, you should also mention that virtually all type punning is undefined behavior under strict aliasing rules. Afaik, the only safe way to get to the bit pattern of a `float` is to use the `memcpy()` function.

Comment: What could be the practical purpose of this particular punning? I guess, inspecting the float-representing bits in the integer?

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev Without seeing more context from the OP it's impossible for anyone else to say.

Comment: @cmaster union punning is not subject to the strict aliasing rule. The only potential for UB is if a trap representation is generated in the type being read.

Answer (score 0):

`union` allows different data types to be stored at the same location. Space is allocated only for the member having `sizeof(member)` maximum.

Once member `f` is initialized, `i` can be accessed from that location.